# AWS set file permission for auto generated files

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, magento, putty

I am runnig my magento site in aws. it has 644 permission for report files but when a new report is generated it's setting it to 640 so i am not able to read or download that file.

How can i set default permission 644 for new auto generated files

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1314/how-to-set-default-file-permissions-for-all-folders-files-in-a-directory

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Web Applications Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/), [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Use setfacl command to set the default permission of the folder in which the reports are stored.

```
sudo setfacl -dm u::rw,g::r,o::r <path>
```